# Efficient update step to this constrained optimization based on the gradient value?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, gradient-descent

i have the following optimization problem:
$$\min f(x) \\ s.t. x_i \geq 0 ,~~\sum{x_i}=1 $$

and $f(x)=\|a-B\big[ C^\top (\sum{x_i^2 D_i})C\big]^{-1} * \big[ C^\top (\sum{x_i^2 h_i})\big]  \|_2^2$ where $\{B,C,D_i\}$ are matrices and $\{x,a,h_i\}$ are vectors.

I have the current value of $x_t$ and i'm interested in finding the best update step to get $x_{t+1}$ . Assume that i can calculate $\nabla_x f(x)$ and maybe also $\nabla_x^2 f(x)$, but i like to update $x_t$ also considering the constraints.

I know that the non-negativity constraint can be handled by projected-gradient update method, but not sure how to handle the other constraint.

Also i'm not sure if the Lagrangian multiplier could be useful here or not!

p.s.: Dimension of $x$ is generally smaller than 100, and even i'm more interested in sparse solutions (as minimum non-zero elements in $x$ as possible in case we can have more than one solution). About the accuracy of $x$, i think no more than 2 digits after the floating point is required.

Comment: How large is the $x$ vector?  a few dozen entries?  in the hundreds?  in the hundreds of millions?  How expensive is it to compute $f(x)$ and its derivatives?  How accurate a solution do you need- is 3 digits good enough, or do you need an answer accurate to 15 digits?

Comment: @BrianBorchers: Good points! I just addressed them. However i' m not sure how expensive is to compute derivatives of $f(x)$ now, but some matrix multiplications along with matrix inverse operation would be involved in that!

Comment: You really can't compute values of $f(x)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This optimization is a special form of the constrained optimization:
$$\min_x f(x) \\ s.t ~~g_i(x) = 0 \\ h_i(x) \leq 0$$

And one efficient way to solve it is to use SQP method which is based on the quadratic approximation of $f(x)$. Although it needs to approximate the Hessian of the Lagrangian function, as the constraints are linear the hessian is only related to $f(x)$ and can be explicitly calculated as $\nabla_{xx}^2 f(x)$.

And for a good update step for $x_t$ i can use the Powell merit function for the line-search.